# possible django race condition

Tags: python, django, signals

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=MyRequestLog)
def steptwo_launcher(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    GeneralLogging(calledBy='MyRequestLog', logmsg='enter steptwo_launcher').save()  # remember to remove this line
    if instance.stepCode == 100:
       GeneralLogging(calledBy='MyRequestLog', logmsg='step code 100 found. launch next step').save()
       nextStep.delay(instance.requestId,False)
```

I think I just witness my code losing a race condition. The backend of my application updates the status of task one, and it writes a stepCode of 100 to the log when the next task should be started.  The front end of the application polls to report the current step back to the end user.

It appears that after the backend created an entry with stepCode 100, the front request came in so soon after, that the if instance.stepCode == 100: was never found to be True. The GeneralLogging only reports one entry at the time of the suspected collision and does not launch the nextstep.

My question is to 1) Confirm this is possible, which I already suspect. and 2) A way to fix this so nextStep is not skipped due to the race condition.

Answer (score 3):

This question lacks a bunch of potentially useful information (e.g. missing code, missing output), but any code of the form

```
if state == x:
    change_state
```

has a potential race condition when multiple control paths hit this code.

Two of the most common ways to handle this problem are (1) locks:

```
with some_lock:
    if state:
        change_state
```

i.e. stop everyone else from hitting this code until we're done, and (2) queues:

```
queue.push(item_to_be_processed)

# somewhere else
item_to_be_processed = queue.pop()
```

A queue/lock implementation in a db could use `select_for_update` and use an extra `processed` field, i.e. let the "writer" process save the model with `processed = False` and have the "reader" process do:

```
from django.db import transaction
...
with transaction.atomic():
    items = MyRequestLog.objects.select_for_update(skip_locked=True).filter(
        stepCode=100, 
        processed=False
    )
    for item in items:
        do_something_useful(item)  # you might want to pull this outside of the atomic block if your application allows (so you don't keep rows locked for an extended period)
        item.processed = True
        item.save()
```

ps: check your database for support (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update)